# Javascript Accessing nested objects in lists i

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I am pretty brand new to coding so please excuse me if this is too much of a basic question. I am going through the challenges on codewars.com to try to increase my coding aptitude. The one I am currently working on has the following prompt:

Lists are data structures composed of nested objects, each containing a single value and a reference to the next object.Write a function listToArray (or list_to_array in Python) that converts a list to an array.

The issue I am having is with the lists. They are nested and keep nesting. My question is how do I access the value for each object if it is nested further and further? I believe if I can figure out how to access the values I should be able to create the array pretty easily. Thanks in advance!

List example:
    `{value: 1, next: {value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}}`

Desired final result:`[1, 2, 3]`

What I have thus far:

```js
function listToArray(list) {
  
  var arr;
  for (var i in list) {
    arr += list [i];
    i++;
  }
//  return arr;
}
var list1 = {value: 1, next: {value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}};
listToArray(list1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lists, you usually use while loops to iterate.

```
function listToArray(list) {
  var arr = [];
  while(list !== null) {
    arr.push(list.value);
    list = list.next;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm trying to understand everything here, mainly the .next property(?). Is next an actual Javascript keyword or is it there merely because it was chosen (eg. could be replaced with "dog" in both the object and function and still accomplish the same task)?

Comment: Second answer. In a js object (`{...}`) you can name the keys as you want, and then you either access them by `object.dog` or `var myVar = 'dog'; object[myVar]` You can try the code with replacing `next` by `dog`.

Comment: `list1.next` is `{value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}` etc

Comment: No, "next" is not a javascript keyword. Look at your data, "next" is one of the keys using which you can reach to a nested level of your data hierarchy.